# How to disable certain rows in grid in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a grid with two checkcolumns and a text field

```
   {
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    id: 'apprId',
    text: '<b>Approve</b>',
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: 'aprvInd'
   },

   {
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    id: 'declId',
    text: '<b>Decline</b>',
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: 'declInd'
   },
   {
    id: 'declResnId',       
    header: '<b>Decline Reasons</b>',
    dataIndex: 'declineReason',
    align: 'center',
    width: 200,     
    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
        maxLength: 100000
      }),
   }
```

if my grid has three rows, first row 'approve' checkbox checked, second row 'decline' checkbox checked and third row nothing checked.
on click of save button, i am doing a rest call and i m passing the data to db, and on success call back , i m reloading grid. 
After reloading, the rows which have approve/decline checked should be disabled along with the 'declineReasons' text field. 
How can i do this?

Comment: What is disabled ? Disable the editor plugin ?

Comment: Disabled means i want to make those fields non-editable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grey out the row I would look at the metaData parameter of the renderer config. Probably the trCls is referenced there.

To disable a checkbox I also would look at the renderer.

To disable the editor plugin look at the beforeedit event.

Comment: i m new to EXTJS, can u please give some piece of code for the same u said.

Comment: any luck @Lorenz Meyer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to look at it. Did you try my recommendations ?

Comment: i am able to disable the editor plugin..but not able to disable the check box.